# Macro replacement list rescanning for replacement

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I'm reading the Standard N1570 about macro replacement and misunderstand some wording from `6.10.3.4`.

> 1 After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted
>   and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing
>   tokens are removed. The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then
>   rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the
>   source file, for more macro names to replace

So after all `#` and `##` are resolved we rescan the replacement list. But the section 2 specifies:

> 2 If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of
>   the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s
>   preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested
>   replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not
>   replaced.

It looks contradictory to me. So what kind of replacement possible in that rescan? I tried the following example:

```
#define FOOBAR(a, b) printf(#a #b)

#define INVOKE(a, b) a##b(a, b)

int main() {
    INVOKE(FOO, BAR); //expands to printf("FOO" "BAR")
}
```

So `INVOKE(FOO, BAR)` expands to `FOOBAR(FOO, BAR)` after substitution of `##`. Then the replacement list `FOOBAR(FOO, BAR)` is rescanned. But the section `2.` specifies that the name of the macro being replaced (`FOOBAR`) is found (yes, defined above) it is not replaced (but actually replaced as can be seen in th demo).

Can you please clarify that wording? What did I miss?

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a272e771e44d5b33)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The (original) macro being replaced is not `FOOBAR`, it's `INVOKE`. When you're expanding `INVOKE` and you find `FOOBAR`, you expand `FOOBAR` normally. However, if `INVOKE` had been found when expanding `INVOKE`, it would no longer be expanded.

Let's take the following code:

```
#define FOOBAR(a, b) printf(#a #b)

#define INVOKE(a, b) e1 a##b(a, b)

int main() {
    INVOKE(INV, OKE);
}
```

I added the `e1` to the expansion of `INVOKE` to be able to visualise how many expansions happen. The result of preprocessing `main` is:

```
e1 INVOKE(INV, OKE);
```

This proves that `INVOKE` was expanded once and then, upon rescanning, not expanded again.

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a16b597bc5a382d9)

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following simple example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

const int FOO = 42;

#define FOO (42 + FOO) 

int main()
{
   printf("%d", FOO);
}
```

Here the output will be 84.

The `printf` will be expanded to:

```
printf("%d", 42 + 42);
```

This means that when the macro `FOO` is expanded, the expansion will stop when the second `FOO` is found. It will not be further expanded. Otherwise, you will end up with endless recursion resulting in: `42 + (42 + (42 + (42 + ....)`

Live demo [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/788c7b9f311df31f).